# Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When pushing to git using visual studio code i am getting the following error

error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-dat

how to resolve this problem